# Tkinter Save Entry data in excel file using for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

Im kind of new to Python and even more on Tkinter. Im trying to create a GUI that save data from entries that i create using a for loop. All the entries are made to receive similar data. I have 20 entries, i append them to a list and next i want them saved on a excel sheet using get() but so far i only manage to save the last value (the entry n° 20). I have tried different ways and i can't get it to work so far. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl.cell import cell
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font






root = Tk()
root.title("Entry Boxes")
root.geometry("1150x600")

book = Workbook()
hoja = book.active

my_entries = list()
fila = 2
col_valor = 1

 

def save_data():
    for entries1 in my_entries:
        fila = 1
        hoja.cell(row=fila, column= 1, value=entries1.get())
        fila +=1
        print(entries1.get())
        book.save('lista_CUIJ_ARCHIVO.xlsx')






#row entries
for y in range (4):
#column entries
    for x in range(5):
        my_entry = Entry(root,width=12,font = "Arial 13 bold")
        my_entry.focus() 
        my_entry.grid(row=y,column=x,padx=55,pady=5,sticky = 'e',ipadx=2,ipady=2,columnspan=1)
        my_entries.append(my_entry)
        L = Label(root, width=5,text="21-0",font = "Arial 12").grid(padx=5, pady=5,sticky = 'w', row=y, column=x)



my_button = Button(root, text="Guardar",command=save_data,font = "Arial 13 bold")
my_button.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=20)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `fila = 1` and `book.save(...)` be outside of the for loop inside `save_data`?

Comment: omg, it was so simple! Thank you so much!